# supervisord multiple commands in single program

Tags: bash, unix, makefile, supervisord

How do I make a program for supervisord execute a command like

```
make && run-my-app.sh
```

It seems to try to pass `&& run-my-app.sh` as arguments to make. I've tried different combinations of quotes around things, but I can't seem to get this syntax right.

Answer (score 21):

You can enclose it in quotes to make it evaluate as two separate commands instead of making it appear && run-my-app.sh as arguments to make.

```
command=/bin/bash -c "make && run-my-app.sh"
```